# Get all relationships connected to a node that are NOT of a particular class

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

So you can easily get all connections to a vertex that *are* of a particular class by querying

`select from Foo where both() in (#42:1)`

This will get all the vertices of class `Foo` that are connected to vertex `#42:1` with either outbound or inbound links.

However what would be the query if I wanted to get all the vertices that are connected to `#42:1` that are *not* instances of class `Foo`?

Does OrientDB natively support this functionality or would I have to do something like an intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not using

```
SELECT * FROM (
... your select query
)
WHERE @class <> 'Foo'
```

Another way could be represented by using Matching Expression

```
MATCH
{E, where:(@class <> 'Foo')}-your_relation->{class:Foo}
RETURN E, F
```

Rob

Comment: Thank you! Also worth noting, that `instanceof` can be used to filter by base class.

Comment: I Think patter matching is "logically" the best way to project only certain classes. OrientDb guys are spending a lot of time in order to improve this product.